# Where do I find Javx.comm or RxTx and how do I get them into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to add COM port access to an application I have in Eclipse.

```
import javax.comm.*;
```

says the import cannot be resolved.  When I search for javax.comm I am also directed to RxTX.  Which do I want and how do I get them into the IDE so that the import will work?

Comment: Did you click "help"-->"install new software" ?

Comment: RxTx http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download

Comment: That site has downloads for binaries, Eclipse Plugins or an update site.  They all download a Jar file.  When I try to use the "install new software" (see above) and point it to the jar files, it says that they do not contain new software.